# recursion equation for running time

Tags: recursion

I need to solve the recursion problem:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + log^2(n)
```

when we call for n element we have log^2(n) actions (except the recursive actions) and so on until we call for 2 element and we have 1 action.

how do I calculate the T(n) running time?

Answer (score 0):

this is SO, it's not the place to put a runtime question.

however, since it's already here, i'm gonna answer that, and probably get -5

the running time is `O(log(n))`. that's because calculating `log^2(n)` will take `O(1)`, so that's insignificant for the run time. so we have

```
T(n) = T(n/2)
```

and that's a classic `O(log(n))`

Comment: 1. can you explaint a bit more? not sure I understand
2. where is the right place?